# React Internationalization Component shallow Render

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, internationalization

I am using React's internationalization.  Example:
export default injectIntl(UsersSearch);

I want to shallow render UsersSearch, meaning want to look at components inside UsersSearch, however when I do this, I get the shallow render of the internationazation Component, which in turn just renders the UserSearch Component.  I need what is inside the UsearsSearch Component.  Is there a guideline on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/tree/master/examples) to react-intl library examples that contains several how-to applications.

Looks like in your case every React component should be wrapped using `injectIntl` function.